# resetting ASP dropdownlist AppendDataBoundItems

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dropdown

I've the following dropdownlist in asp:that's bound to SQL database to retrieve values based on a query.

```
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="VALUE" DataValueField="VALUE">
    <asp:ListItem Value=" " Selected="true" Text="--Select One--"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT &quot;VALUE&quot; FROM TABLENAME WHERE (column= xx)">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The thing is that I want to make the first selection ---select one--- 
now when I want to reset the textfields, i want to reset the dropdown list to the value ---select one---, in javascript, but I couldn't.

I reset the textfilds in asp.net as follows:

```
 document.getElementById('<%= txt_field01.ClientID %>').value = '';
 document.getElementById('<%= txt_field01.ClientID %>').value = '';
```

I need your support and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
var drop = document.getElementById('<%=dropdownID.ClientID%>').querySelectorAll("option:selected");
```

you can use one of this options below

```
$(drop).empty();
```

OR

```
drop.value = '';
```

OR

```
$('#mydropID').val('');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this didn't work it gave me invalid argument at the var line